# UISlider in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, uikit, uislider

In a Cocoa app I added a UISlider. If I run the program without adding any code then I can drag the slider left and right. However, if I assign an IBOutlet to it, once I touch the slider, the application exits. Why is that?

Comment: What is the outlet? By "exit", do you mean "crash"? Does the outlet really exist in the implementation file of the object you've connected it to?

Comment: The application just exits to the iPhone simulator. There are no error messages. In the implementation file I've just made an IBOutlet that doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you put a statement in the outlet method, and put a breakpoint on that statement, does it hit? Can you paste in any text that appears in the Console while you're running the app?

Comment: I don't think the breakpoint hits. Here's the console output:

This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 358.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""AppController.m":15" resolved
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved the problem. If I make the application a Window-based application, then I don't have any problems. If I make the application a View-based application, then the problem occurs. Why is that?

Comment: I just created a view-based (iPhone) app; added a UISlider and connected it to an IBOutlet in my controller sub-class. Build, run and… no-crash. If you have a minimal Xcode project delete the <build> folder and zip everything and send it to me: <geowar1 @ mac.com> (no spaces). If I can reproduce the crash I'll figure out why and post a response here.